# How to make chart.js animate/growth/alive in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am on PHP 7.2 Laravel 5.8 and I'm using Chart.js

As we all know Laravel is purely MVC. I call my API in the controller, and then pass it on the view and plot the chart.

My Chart does not seem to animate growth.

What do I mean by that animate growth ?

See this sample here : https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/line-stacked.html

Answer (score 0):

your canvas should be wrapped within an element with defined width/height

Comment: Will it growth then if I do that ??

Comment: this has nothing to do with laravel itself - if its not animating @kyo that means you are embedding it wrong - without you being more specific than "its not working" we can only guess ... I'd suggest you to post a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milostimotic/e8n4xd4z/) with your non-animating code

Answer (score -1):

Try with HTMLCanvasElement.getContext(). Like following
new Chart(document.getElementById('bwChart').getContext("2d"), config);ddd

Comment: @kyo you missed the HTMLCanvasElement.getContext() if you add, it will work fine ;)